# Loop through each element in array

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to loop through the below JSON format object for which I have the code below

```
private Integer k1;
private List<Integer> k2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// getter setters
```

Incoming JSON object which will be mapped to the POJO request

```
[{"k1":1,"k2":[2,3,4]},{"k1":2,"k2":[5,6,7]}]
```

I am trying to iterate over the request data and get the value of k1 and k2. How can I achieve this. It will be really grateful for any help provided.

I have tried below code, but is there any better wat to achieve this using streams

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
}
```

I want to iterate each element to get the value of k1 and then k2 to get all values. I am confused how to loop through the outer array and then getting the value from inner array of k2.

> Expected Output

```
select * from table where col1=1 and col2=2;
select * from table where col1=1 and col2=3;
select * from table where col1=1 and col2=4;
select * from table where col1=2 and col2=5;
select * from table where col1=2 and col2=6;
//Similarly all values iterated and made db call each time
```

Making a call to DB using the values of k1 for col1 and k2 for col2

Comment: I suppose you have a list of POJOs after mapping? Then you can stream it. The actual operation depends on what you want to do. Do you just want to print it or do something different with it?

Comment: `map.entrySet()` returns a `Set<String, Integer>` which does have a `stream()` method. Is that what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason to use a Map here? It seems like a list could work with the object you give as an example.

Comment: I have fetch the value of k1 and k2 so that I can process further using these values.

Comment: That is a bit ambiguous. So you want to save `.map()` them. What you want to map them to? A list of integers? You are not specifying the desired result

Comment: In the beginning of your question, you have a `private Integer k1; private List<Integer> k2;`, but at the end, you suddenly have a `Map<String, Integer>`. And according to your question’s title, there is an array involved…

Comment: "*Incoming JSON object which will be mapped to the POJO request*" (1) what you shown is JSON Array `[...]` which *holds* two JSON Objects `[{..}, {..}]`. (2) How will it happen? What is the relationship of your POJO and `map` you are trying to iterate?

Comment: Updated my question with more data

Comment: `list.forEach(e -> e.getK2().forEach(e2 -> System.out.println(e.getK1() + "=" + e2)));` but instead of printing, you make the DB call

Comment: This SQL-query doesn't explain what you're trying to achieve in Java.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko  Hope now the SQL query is clear

Answer (score 1):

convert your json to pojo using objectMapper. It will be a list. then iterate over the list and call respective getters to fetch values

```java
class Custom{
    private Integer k1;
    private List<Integer> k2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}



String json = "[{\"k1\":1,\"k2\":[2,3,4]},{\"k1\":2,\"k2\":[5,6,7]}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Custom> customsList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, Custom[].class));
customsList.stream().forEach(cl -> System.out.println(cl.getK1()+":"+cl.getK2()));
```

Comment: But in this code how we are iterating the values of k2 ?

Comment: You don't need to generate a stream just in order to apply `forEach()`.

Comment: @user4324324 Add another `foreach` for `c1.k2`.    Eg: `customsList.forEach(c->{c.k2.forEach(i->{ System.out.println("K1 " + c.k1+ " :: K2 "+i);});});`

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is using [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
List<Custom> list = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Custom>>(){}.getType());
```

Now as mentioned by [@NikitaBansal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11378797/nitika-bansal) all you have to do is iterate through the list and construct your SQL syntax .

```
for(Custom obj : list){
    for(Integer i : obj.k2 ){
        System.out.println("K1 " + c.k1+ " :: K2 "+i);  
        //your code
    }
}
```

It's completely up to you , how you are going to traverse it.